# How to extend functionality of geth (module, addon)?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs, golang

Is there a way to **extend** functionality of geth using some sort of plugins, modules or addons?

However, I haven't found any information about the topic.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Geth doesn't support this directly. You would need to fork the client and do whatever modifications/add systems as you wish

There's also a fork of Geth called [PluGeth](https://github.com/openrelayxyz/plugeth) which supports an easier way to write client plugins in Go. I haven't personally used it, though I know the folks who maintain it